# Numpy array method truncating least significant digits?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The input array arrs is converted to numpy array as follows:

```
matarr = np.array(arrs)
```

Here are the first elements of both arrays:

```
arrs[1][0:10]
[34550.0, 24087.0, 13853.0, 14686.0, 24658.0, 42803.0, 69052.0, 99523.0, 121035.0, 126818.0]
```

And here is the numpy conversion:

```
matarr[1][0:10]
['3455' '2408' '1385' '1468' '2465' '4280' '6905' '9952' '1210' '1268']
```

It seems that we got a floor operation on the truncated value to 4 significant digits.  What might be going on here?

Comment: What type of data is in `arrs`? It looks like numpy found a string and decided you wanted an array of 4-character strings. You probably have a bug in the creation of `arrs`, since I doubt you want mixed floats and strings in there.

Comment: Also, for debugging, it's generally a better idea to provide the `repr` representation of your data than just `print`ing it.

Comment: yea ur correct. I have filtered the labels column out and numpy is happy now.